# the balance in genesis file is it in ether or wei?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

In genesis.json file I have this balance :

```
 "bd7a14e103ffa97ec5fd96d9975adb1b52756ef3": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
```

the hex number is the balance but does the value of ether or wei ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is in wei.

For a source that supports this assertion specifically for genesis files, have a look in [`genesis.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/genesis.go#L294).

```
// GenesisBlockForTesting creates and writes a block in which addr has the given wei balance.
func GenesisBlockForTesting(db ethdb.Database, addr common.Address, balance *big.Int) *types.Block {
    g := Genesis{Alloc: GenesisAlloc{addr: {Balance: balance}}}
    return g.MustCommit(db)
}
```